# How to skip first item if got second on some time period on RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I need to perform some action in X seconds after received an event (represented any data item rxJava). But if got another event before X seconds ends, timer reset and action need to be performed again in X seconds.

Another words, we have UI elements with which user may interact. After X seconds of user's inactivity with this UI element we need to perform some action.
Trivial solution could look like:

```
Disposable disp;
void init() {
             final Flowable<Boolean> flowable = 
mapDragOrZoomSubject.delay(TIME_X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP);
        disp = flowable. ...subscribeWith(ACTION);  // <-- action in X seconds of inactivity
    }

void gotNewUserInteraction() {
    disp.dispose();
    init();
}
```

How to do this without disposing and re-creation Flowable basing on some rxJava operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with rxJava, but the operator you are looking for is probably [debounce](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#debounce). So maybe something like this:

```
Disposable disp;
void init() {
             final Flowable<Boolean> flowable = 
mapDragOrZoomSubject.delay(TIME_X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP);
        disp = flowable
                 ...
                 .debounce(TIME_X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .subscribeWith(ACTION);  // <-- action in X seconds of inactivity
    }

void gotNewUserInteraction() {
    disp.dispose();
    init();
}
```

Comment: debounce() is similar thing, but what debounce is doing is removing all subsequent values after that first value, f.e.:
1,2,3  ->  1 

What I need is some revers debounce as I need leave only latest action (with its X second timer), so it may look like 
1, 2, 3 -> 3

Comment: The documentation I linked says something different. If you look at the debounce example comment in the doc. it does exactly what you want: 1,2,3 -> 3

Comment: Yes, really, let I try it

Answer (score 0):

Try the `throttleWithTimeout(...)` operator:

```
@Test
public void testThrottleWithTimeout()
{
    Subject<String> eventSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    TestObserver<String> observer = eventSubject
            .throttleWithTimeout( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler )
            .test();

    eventSubject.onNext( "foo" );
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy( 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    observer.assertNoValues();

    eventSubject.onNext( "bar" );
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy( 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    observer.assertNoValues();

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy( 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    observer.assertValue( "bar" );
}
```